# Getting high resolution DEM for a location

Tags: dem, data, resolution, srtm

As a part of my project, I want high resolution (10m approx) DEM for my desired location.

How and where can I get it?

I already tried with 30m DEM obtained from USGS.
I am getting blurry DEM, if I clip my area of interest from the 30m DEM obtained from USGS.
As USGS provides the DEM only for an existing huge blocks of area, there is no other option to clip my required small block of area from the huge block of DEM, which is resulting in blury DEM image.

It would be resolved if I get high resolution DEM.

How can I find the source of the data?

Comment: Hi Kaushik Vezzu, welcome to GIS SE. Please be more precise: How could we anser your question if you don't tell us what "my area of interest" actually is? Sothern Italy or Northern Brazil, Eastern Mongolia or Western Canada, ... ? As a first idea: did you have a look at this? https://opendem.info/

Comment: 10 meters (DTED Level 2) isn't "high resolution", certainly not for such a tiny area. Open sources for LiDAR data are limited, and the tiny (and not specified) area makes it unlikely. When my wife wanted to design a new garden for our house, she contracted an engineering firm to survey the yard and generate a 6" contour map. 20 years later, this is a task for a LiDAR drone. Either way, offering data sources is too *opinion-based* for our *problem-solving* format.

Answer (score 1):

Use **https://apps.nationalmap.gov/lidar-explorer/#/**

[image]

The darker the green the higher the accuracy

DEM is available by using the tools (ctrl create window)

**1m DEM** or 10m is available depending on your area of interest (AOI)

Example
[image]